# SQL Insert statement syntax

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, insert

Basically what I am doing is that upon clicking a button, the program will extract data from a particular row according to what the user chose and place it in a different table by using `INSERT`. The following is the code.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        const String connectionString = "Data Source = Vanessa-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = IUMDC; Connect Timeout = 15; Integrated Security = true";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        //int SituationID1; 
        label24.Show();

        foreach (SitID x in Sittbl)
        {
            if (x.ID == Convert.ToInt16(comboBox1.SelectedItem))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Situation WHERE SituationID=" + x.SitIDs, con);
                    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        sitid1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                        name1 = dr[4].ToString();
                        incident1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[1]);
                        charges1 = dr[5].ToString();
                        nature1 = dr[2].ToString();
                    }

                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Database failed to connect" + ex.Message);
                }

                //SituationID = x.SitIDs;
            }
        }

        try
        {                       
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CurrentSit VALUES (" + sitid1 + ",'" + incident1.ToString("YYYY-mm-DD") + "', '" + nature1 + "', '" + name1 + "', '" + charges1 + "'", con);
           SqlDataReader dr1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
           con.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database failed to connect" + ex.Message);
        }
        //Situation Sit = new Situation();
        //Sit.ShowDialog();
    }
```

My code fails and says

> "Incorrect syntax near *row item*"

The types of the two tables are the same and I have tried to test this thoroughly!

Comment: When doing an `INSERT`, you're not returning a collection of data - therefore, you should use `command1.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead of the `.ExecuteReader()` where you then just ignore the reader, really....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like your last sql statement is not correct. Maybe the reason is usage of apostrophe in your sql stament, but you should not care about it. I explan in the middle of my answer why you shouldn't care.

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CurrentSit VALUES (" + sitid1 + ",'" + incident1.ToString("YYYY-mm-DD") + "', '" + nature1 + "', '" + name1 + "', '" + charges1 + "'", con);
```

To find out what is exactly the problem, you can specify column names instead. But I suggest you to use *parameterized query* not even necessary to specify your column names.

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CurrentSit VALUES(@sitid1, @incident1, @nature1, @name1, @charges1)", con);

command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitid1", sitid1);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@incident1", incident1.ToString("YYYY-mm-DD"));
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nature1", nature1);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", name1);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@charges1", charges1);

command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*. This kind of codes are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

Also as Marc [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127187/sql-insert-statement-syntax/17127241#comment24784665_17127187), there is no point to use [`ExecuteReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) for this sql statement because it is only `INSERT` data, doesn't returns any data. Because of that, you only need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) in this case.

Comment: You have no idea of how thankful I am right now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying the columns in your query:

```
"INSERT INTO CurrentSit (sitid, incident, nature, name1, charges) VALUES (" + sitid1 + ",'" + incident1.ToString("YYYY-mm-DD") + "', '" + nature1 + "', '" + name1 + "', '" + charges1 + "'", con)";
```

As an additional note, also learn to use paramerterized queries. For instance:

```
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name1", name1);  
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@charges1", charges1);
```

http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/

Answer (score 4):

Your immediate problem is that your `INSERT` statement has some invalid syntax it in; most likely one of the values you are using to build it has an apostrophe in it that's terminating your string early.

Your bigger problem is that you *should never ever* build insert statements this way. Besides being highly prone to errors of the sort you're seeing, it's also a classic opening to SQL injection attacks. (Imagine, for example, if a situation's nature `foo'); drop table situation; --`).

You should be using parameterized queries:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO CurrentSit VALUES (@sitid, @incident, @nature, @name, @charges)"
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sitid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sitid1;
// etc.
```